# Algebra equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let be $$ax^3=by^3=cz^3$$   and $$\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=1}$$, proof that $$ \sqrt[3]{ax^2+by^2+cz^2}=\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}$$.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't proved what you asked for but am hoping this might help you get to the proof.

From:$$ax^3=by^3=cz^3$$we can deduce:$$by^2=\frac{ax^3}{y}$$and:$$cz^2=\frac{ax^3}{z}$$$$\therefore ax^2+by^2+cz^2=ax^3\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)=ax^3$$$$\therefore \sqrt[3]{ax^2+by^2+cz^2}=x\sqrt[3]{a}$$And, by symmetry we can also prove that:$$\sqrt[3]{ax^2+by^2+cz^2}=x\sqrt[3]{a}=y\sqrt[3]{b}=z\sqrt[3]{c}$$

I hope this helps.